# Markdown relative anchor links do not work

Tags: support

I'd like to add some brief links like this:

link text (i.e. `[link text](#anchor)`)

So that they are converted to this:

```
<a href="#anchor">link text</a>
```

But so far I've noticed that it's impossible in comments.

For example, if I'd like to add a comment like this:

```
Please compare your answer to [this answer posted earlier by Jon](#125135235),
they are almost identical.
```

or

```
Per your comment, I've added my answer [here](#543543534).
```

how can I do this without absolute links?

Comment: Not sure I understand, what's wrong with the "Share" link under each answer?

Comment: I wanted to get a link that does not need a page reload, and is relative, and is short.

Comment: Oooooh, with*out* absolute links! Time for a coffee...

Comment: You are right... coffee sounds good :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts is slightly different but what I was looking for - so to help others find **a suggestion about anchor links that is not limited to answers.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those links would break in the (admittedly unlikely) event that answers spanned multiple pages.

Instead, use `/a/543543534` for a short link: [blah blah blah](/a/323894).

Comment: Hmmm... so it seems there is no way of getting a reliable short address that does not need a page reload?

Comment: Not reliable, no.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Shog9 there seems to be no way of getting a 100% reliable link that is short, relative, and does not require a page reload.

Having this (i.e. `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323893/markdown-relative-anchor-links-do-not-work`) question and it's accepted answer as an example, below are possible solutions.

- If you go for ?% reliable, relative, and does not require a page reload:

  ```
  [link text](/questions/323893/markdown-relative-anchor-links-do-not-work#323894)
  ```

  Example: see [answer by Shog9](/questions/323893/markdown-relative-anchor-links-do-not-work#323894).
- If you go for 100% reliable, short and relative, then it requires a page reload:

  ```
  [link text](/a/323894)
  ```

  Example: see [answer by Shog9](/a/323894).